# Display progress dialog for multiple loaders?

Tags: android

I have 3 CursorLoader in my activity and I want to start progress dialog when the first loader is started and I want to dismiss dialog when the last loader is finished.

Does exist standart solution to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

why don't you just raise flags(using boolean) when each one starts and remove it when it's done.. when each one finishes it checks the other two flags.. the progress dialog is dismissed when all flags are down